# C#: инициализация строки с JSON

Tags: c#, json

Есть такие классы:

```
public abstract class Request
{
    public string ToJson() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
}

public class LicenseRequest : Request
{
    public string loginHash;
    public string passwordHash;
    public string macAddress;

    public string pluginName;
    public string pluginVersion;
    public string dllHash;
}

public class LicenseAnswer
{
    public bool success;
    public int errorCode;

    public bool isOutdated;
    public string linkToUpdate;

    public string license;
}

public class RegistrationRequest : Request
{
    public string login;
    public string password;
    public string macAddress;
}

public class RegistrationAnswer
{
    public bool success;
    public int errorCode;
}
```

Можно ли написать универсальный метод или конструктор для абстрактного класса `Answer`, чтобы объект инициализировался/заполнялся из JSON-строки?

Comment: Для абстрактного - нет. В остальном -- почему бы и нет?

Comment: Тут вам, по всей видимости, понадобятся обобщения. Что-то типа того `public abstract class Request<T> where T : class`, но лучше сделать не абст.класс, а интерфейс. Да, вы намеренно вместо свойств используете публичные поля?

Comment: Не очень намеренно) Хотелось бы написать что-то вроде public void LoadFromJson(string jsonString) {this = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<this.GetType()>(jsonString); }